# Upload 2 files with uploadify

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

Hello I want to have a form where to have posibility to upload 2 files with jquery uploadify. But I want to have 2 select buttons, for each file one select button. I don't to use multiple upload. Is this possible?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#upload_cv').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg' : 'uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder'    : 'upload',
        'fileExt'   : '*.doc;*.docx;*.pdf',
        'fileDesc'  : 'Documents (.doc, .docx, .pdf)',
        'sizeLimit' : 2097152,
        'auto'      : false,
        'onAllComplete':  function(event,data) {
            $('#upload_letter').uploadifyUpload();
        }
    });

    $('#upload_letter').uploadify({
        'uploader'  : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg' : 'uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder'    : 'upload',
        'auto'      : false

      });
});

    function submitForm() {
        if($("#myform").validate().form())
            $('#upload_cv').uploadifyUpload();
    }
</script>
```

For second file upload_letter I need to fire onAllComplete even if I don't select a file! How can I do this?!

And how I will get file name of uploaded file?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `uploadify` on both buttons.

Comment: Ok, I really need some help with this, I have a form with some text fields and with 2 files upload. First file is obligatory and the second optional. I want first to validate first text fields, and then to  upload first file, and second if exist, and if everything is fine to send the form.

Comment: So you want the buttons to appear after validation?